# Why is only one of my two studio strobes firing?

Tags: canon, flash, softbox

I am a beginner in photography and I am having trouble with my Falconeyes SS-350H with Softbox lights. We have two lights, but only one is flashing when using the RF-DD4 wireless flash trigger.

The flashes are both functioning well. However, when I take a picture only one is flashing when I press the test button on the transmitter. It's like it's only flashing where you connect the receiver, but when I connect the receiver to the other light (the one currently not flashing when taking a picture) it will flash, and the other one does not.

Comment: Does your strobe fire if used _without_ the softbox? Does it fire with the test button? What if you switch the triggers?

Comment: yes it fires, the softbox flashes where the trigger is being connected. both flashes are fine. testing it with the test button, only one is flashing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I followed that. How can they both be fine if one doesn't work? Can you explain more precisely what does and does not function, in what situations?

Comment: the flash of both softbox is functioning well. however when i taking picture only 1 softbox is flashing also when pressing the testing button for the transmitter. its like its only flashing where you connect the receiver, but when i connected it to the other softbox( the softbox who is currently not flashing when taking picture) it will flash, the other one is not.

Comment: Are the on the same channels? Sounds like the heads may be misconfigured.

Comment: Do you have a separate receiver for each softbox? Or only the single receiver?

Comment: only 1 receiver, last monthn its working fine. transmitter and receiver is on the same channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using external radio triggers to trip your studio lights, you need one radio receiver unit for each light--so for your setup, you would need **two** RFDD-4 receiver units and one transmitter.  The lights do not have any internal way of receiving a radio signal, so it's only the light that's connected to your single receiver unit that will flash.

However. The SS-350HD lights also have a built-in optical slave. The photo sensor is that bump on the top of the unit.  It can sense when the other flash goes off.  So, for the light that doesn't have a radio receiver attached to it, turn on the optical slave mode by pressing the "REMOTE" button on the back of the unit (it's labelled Photo Sensor Switch on [page 2 of the manual](http://www.falconeyes.com.hk/manage/Downloads/20150708055122_FM1304_SS-H-HD_eng_.pdf#page=2)).

Comment: the remote is always on, but its not flashing, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Is the sensor blocked? And remote should be off on the one attached to the radio receiver. You need line of sight from the flash that IS firing to trip the one that isn't.  This is why it might be be simpler to just purchase another receiver.